# Clean Architecture, good approaches to avoid hard-coding the creation of entities on the Use Case

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, clean-code, clean-architecture

I have an Use Case that has an `UseCaseInput` (which is a parameter object of the use case) and an `UseCaseOutput` which is the output object, the `UseCaseInput` has lots of parameters in which will be used in various dependencies as parameters **(repositories, adapters, etc)**, some Entities are going to be persisted in the database, and for that, I need to create an object instance for these Entities, but I got stuck on the problem of creating these entities without hard-coding it on the Use Case, because, among other problems, I cannot test it.

passing an entity factory/builder instance via constructor makes sense to me, but since it's "just transforming" the Use Case's parameter object into an Entity (or entities) may be too specific to this Use Case and it will overflood the constructor with lots of possible entity constructors or is that OK?

what are some good approaches to mitigate this "problem"?

**code example of just one Entity:**

```
class UseCaseInput {
    public param1;
    public param2;
    public param3;
    public extraParam1;
    public extraParam2;
}

class UseCaseOutput {
    public param: number;
}

class MyEntity {
    public domainParam1;
    public domainParam2;

    constructor(/**assign */) {
    }
}

class MyUseCase
{
    public constructor(
        //repository dependency 1,
        //repository dependency 2,
        //adapter dependency 1,
    )
    {
    }

    public execute(useCaseInput: UseCaseInput): UseCaseOutput
    {
        // some other operations
        // more operations

        // Create entity with properties of UseCaseInput
        const myEntity = new MyEntity(UseCaseInput);

        // Persist Entity to Repository
        // this.repository.save(myEntity)

        return new UseCaseOutput(/** ... */);
    }
}
```

Comment: `but I got stuck on the problem of creating these entities without hard-coding it on the Use Case, because, among other problems, I cannot test it.` What can not you test? On the other hand, `MyEntity` should not be coupled to `useCaseInput` since `myEntity` belongs to an inner layer that doesn't know anything about the business layer. You will need to map business models to domain models in a different way.

Comment: I cannot mock the hard-coded entity if it's created inside the Use Case, I don't see how the  "useCaseInput" is couple to the entity, it's just "input data" to be used in the use case, which happens to also be used to create the MyEntity, how would you proceed to create the entity?

Comment: `UseCaseInput`is strictly defined by the use case which required it, hence declared in the business layer, which is on top of the domain layer. If `MyEntity` belongs to the domain (and it should since `repository` uses it) then there's no way for `MyEntity` to be aware of the `userCaseInput` unless you couple the domain to the business (bad). On the other hand, if you are testing `MyUseCase`, you don't need to know what's going on inside, you only test that *given the use-case X, when executes with the input I, then result in output O*. `new MyEntity(..)` is implementation details.

Comment: i see that point, that makes sense.
so you think it's overengineering to have a builder for the entity?

Comment: Depends on the complexity of constructing instances of the entity.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to provide more detail about your UseCaseInput parameters. Based on the information you provided, we can do some improvement on the input model design.

Usually, the input model it's a bag of properties collected from its client side. It'd better to be modeled as a composition of some specific purposed models (COJO bean):

```
public class UseCaseInput {
   
   private ContextParameters contextParameters;     

   private ModelForDomainService model;

}

public class ContextParameters {
   // context parameters
}

public class ModelForDomainService {
   // properties ...
}
```

The benefit is you have dedicate models delcared for corresponding domain services. Then you can decouple domain service from the UseCaseInput bean. It will make you code testable and also flexible on changes. Further, you can apply more sophisticated validation logic on these models to guard against any garbage input as early as possible.

```
// Use it in your application layer code

class MyUseCase
{
    public constructor(
        //repository dependency 1,
        //repository dependency 2,
        //adapter dependency 1,
    )
    {
    }

    public execute(modelForDomainService: ModelForDomainService): UseCaseOutput
    {
        // some other operations
        // more operations

        // Create entity with properties of UseCaseInput
        const myEntity = new MyEntity(modelForDomainService);

        // Persist Entity to Repository
        // this.repository.save(myEntity)

        return new UseCaseOutput(/** ... */);
    }
}
```

The basic principal is you shouldn't leak non-necessary information from high layer (Application) into the lower layer (Domain Service). If the whole procedure requires a few domain services working together, you should map the input into different Domain Service Input Models in your application layer code then dispatch it to specific services.

By the way, the pseudo code is written in Java.

Comment: i see, it's a coincidence that the UseCaseInput properties have the same name as the MyEntity's, so it's not necessarily/intentional leaked outwards, but MyEntity is still hard-coded, what happens if I want to mock it for specific scenarios of the Use Case? like throw an exception, return invalid data, etc

Comment: Then pass invalid useCaseInputs to make MyEntity constructor to fail

Comment: To @Thiago, MyEntity is part of your domain, it is not hard-coded. Instead, it is the contact point between your domain service and application layer. You can create any new MyEntity instances to test your code for different scenarios. MyEntity defined what the data format your service should accept. You don't need to worry about how MyEntity get created, that help you seperate the concerns.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot mock the hard-coded entity if it's created inside the Use Case

`MyUserCase` is expected to code some logic or even data types as **implementation details**. Right now, `new MyEntity(...)` is one of these details.

You don't have to test implementation details. Ever. Moreover, from the testing standpoint, you don't even know that `MyUseCase` is building anything. The only you know about `MyUseCase` is leaked by its interface

- `UseCaseInput`, `UseCaseOutput` via `execute()` method
- `RepositoryA`, `RepositoryB` via `constructor` method

That's all you have to test `MyUseCase`.

> what happens if I want to mock it (MyEntity) for specific scenarios of the Use Case?

Follow the grammar **given** (a component), **when** (input), **then** (output).

> Given `MyUseCase` when `invalid useCaseInput` then `error`.

If you need `repository 1` to cast an error, then mock `repository 1`, make a new instance of `MyUseCase` with the mocked repository, call `execute()` with valid data and see what happens.

> Given `MyUseCase` when `repository fails` then `error`

Finally,

> so you think it's overengineering to have a builder for the entity?

Right now, given the above code. Yes, I think so.

On one hand, nothing makes me believe that instantiating `MyEntity` is hard. So, why do I need a builder?

On the other hand, there's no way for `MyUseCase` to fail at instantiating `MyEntity`. It's not implementing logic for it. It's only forwarding an input. Whatever is creating `UseCaseInput` is outside of the use-case, so I can impersonate it from my testing code.